# Timezones in Django1.4

Tags: python, django, timezone, django-1.4

My project was originally on Django 1.3 and now I'm migrating it to Django 1.4.

```
#models.py
class my_model(models.Model):
    traveldate = models.DateTimeField(null=False,db_index=True,blank=True)
```

Setting file:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
USE_TZ = True
```

Say item is an instance of my_model. Then in Django 1.3,

```
>>> item.traveldate
>>> datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 27, 8, 35)
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
>>> datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 23, 16, 1, 32, 371116)
```

The `item.traveldate` stored in database and `datetime.datetime.now()` both are local time and time-zone-aware datetime objects, so we can compare them fine.

But now,

```
>>> item.traveldate
>>> datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 27, 8, 35, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> timezone.now()
>>> datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 23, 10, 32, 57, 609166, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

`timezone.now()` is an aware datetime object with utc timezone, which is fine. But the value which was stored in database seem to have been taken as it is and considered to be utc, while it was on IST timezone. And this breaks my comparison!

For new data, this would work fine as it will be converted to UTC before saving in database. But what about the old data?

Do I actually need to convert all my data from local to UTC?? That would be a lot of work given the number of models present.
Please suggest if anything else can be done.

Comment: Check your USE_TZ setting. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_TZ If you're using the same settings file from 1.3, it should still be the default value (False) which should give the naive, 1.3-era behavior. But if you generated a new settings.py, USE_TZ would be True, and it'll try to use tz-aware datetimes.

Comment: @AdamKG The correct setting is being picked and its tz-aware datetimes. But my issue is: it's converting the values in my database into utc tz-aware datetimes directly while actually those datetimes are local times. Please read my question.

Comment: Django has no way of telling whether the saved timestamps are UTC or not. You can't have it both ways: either you have USE_TZ False and local-TZ data in your DB, or you have to migrate your data to UTC.

Comment: @AdamKG But it's a major major task to convert all my data to UTC. I wanted to use this feature because the documentation says its the right way to do things, comparable to `unicode` in python. My project as such doesn't "need" this feature. So it'll be a big overhead for me to convert all the data.

Comment: OK, so don't do it "the right way" then. There's no third option here, the Django ORM can't divine which timestamps were saved "the right way" and which weren't. If you want to do it correctly, you have to fix the data that was written incorrectly. If you don't want to migrate data, then the timestamps won't be in UTC, and unless you keep the same `TIME_ZONE` setting you used in 1.3 and set `USE_TZ = False`, the timestamps will be incorrect.

Comment: I had the same problem and finally I set USE_TZ = False